# How to change my job configuration to add file name dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which reads from a db then outputs to a multiple csv's. Inside my db I have a special column named divisionId. A CSV file should exist for every distinct value of divisionId. I split out the data using a ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.

At the moment I have an ItemWriter bean defined for every distinct value of divisionId. The beans are the same, it's only the file name that is different.

How can I change the configuration below to create a file with the divisionId automatically pre-pended to the file name without having to register a new ItemWriter for each divisionId?

I've been playing around with @JobScope and @StepScope annotations but can't get it right.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Bean
public Step readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep() {
    return  commonJobConfig.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep")
                .<MasterList,MasterList>chunk(commonJobConfig.chunkSize)
                .reader(commonJobConfig.queryStagingDbReader())
                .processor(masterListOutputProcessor())
                .writer(masterListFileWriter())
                .stream((ItemStream) divisionMasterListFileWriter45())
                .stream((ItemStream) divisionMasterListFileWriter90())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<MasterList> masterListFileWriter() {
    BackToBackPatternClassifier classifier = new BackToBackPatternClassifier();
    classifier.setRouterDelegate(new DivisionClassifier());
    classifier.setMatcherMap(new HashMap<String, ItemWriter<? extends MasterList>>() {{
        put("45", divisionMasterListFileWriter45());
        put("90", divisionMasterListFileWriter90());
    }});
    ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<MasterList> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<MasterList>();
    writer.setClassifier(classifier);
    return writer;
}   

@Bean
public ItemWriter<MasterList> divisionMasterListFileWriter45() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<MasterList> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(commonJobConfig.outDir, "45_masterList" + "" + ".csv")));
    writer.setHeaderCallback(masterListFlatFileHeaderCallback());
    writer.setLineAggregator(masterListFormatterLineAggregator());
    return writer;
}   

@Bean
public ItemWriter<MasterList> divisionMasterListFileWriter90() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<MasterList> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(commonJobConfig.outDir, "90_masterList" + "" + ".csv")));
    writer.setHeaderCallback(masterListFlatFileHeaderCallback());
    writer.setLineAggregator(masterListFormatterLineAggregator());
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Are the amount of divisionId fixed? In other words, do you know beforehand that the values are the two values 45 and 90? Or are those two just examples of one of the many possible values?

Comment: DivisionId's are fixed. 0 to 100 in increments of 5. But I'm trying to implement dynamically bc after I get what's been asked above working I have an extra requirement to pass in a from date and to date into the job as job parameters and further breakdown the file by another column in my data named start date. I.e. For every date between the from date and to date Job parameters I need to break down my file further by start date. So my end result would be file names that look like divisionId_startDate_masterList.csv.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a pretty complex way of doing this. I followed a tutorial at https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples/wiki/Rename-Files.

The premise is to use the step execution context to place the file name in it.